# How to inject content of CSS file into HTML in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

I need to insert the content of a stylesheet into the `<head>` of an HTML page. How can I do it in Gulp?

Before (what I have):

```
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

After (what I want):

```
<head>
  <style>
     p { color: pink; }
  </style>
</head>
```

Note that I do not need to inline CSS into the elements, but just put the contents of CSS in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could easily use [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace), like so:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    replace = require('gulp-replace'),
    fs = require('fs');

// in your task
return gulp.src(...)
  .pipe(replace(/<link href="style.css"[^>]*>/, function(s) {
      var style = fs.readFileSync('style.css', 'utf8');
      return '<style>\n' + style + '\n</style>';
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(...));
```

You can also easily modify the replacement RegEx to work with different files, too.

```
return gulp.src(...)
  .pipe(replace(/<link href="([^\.]\.css)"[^>]*>/g, function(s, filename) {
      var style = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      return '<style>\n' + style + '\n</style>';
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(...));
```

Comment: Your second regular expression would only match one-symbol-named css files. You should correct it like this: 
`/<link href="([^\.]+\.css)"[^>]*>/g`

Comment: I would also caution here for references in the CSS. In a file like `/styles.css`, this is fine. However, if you are sourcing something such as `/css/styles.css`, any relative paths for media, fonts, etc may be incorrect if you inline it using this method.

Comment: Had to change regex to `/<link[^>]+href="(.*?.css)"[^>]*>/g` to capture links with attributes

Answer (score -4):

You can inline the styles using import:

```
<style> @import "style.css"; </style>
```

Comment: that actually worked for me.. Wired thing tough - in the page source and dev tools I see only `@import "mystyle.css";` but the the actual css. On the other hand page get styled.. any ideas? is this expected?
PS: don't get the down votes

Comment: This is not much different than using the `<link>` element. The browser still has to go and find the `style.css` file, so it's not completing the goal of injecting the physical styles into the HTML page.