# Gulp Module to read file content and use it in pipe

Tags: npm, gulp, gulp-babel

**Usecase (abstract):**

I have several files in which a certain value to be read. This value I want to use in the same pipeline again to read out a file and inject it.

**Example HTML file source:**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <link href="foo/bar/anyfilename.css">
   </head>
</html>
```

**Example HTML file dest:**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <style type="text/css">
       .example-class {
         color: red;
       }
     </style>
   </head>
</html>
```

I found various modules, but nothing suitable for my usecase.

Comment: Ok, this was a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23834812/676406

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) if you really want to replace a string tag with some other content in your pipe.

However, if you are trying to inject references you should look at [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject).

Tip: Try not to use inline styles if you can help it.